# "Enter Paramater Value" Box for deleted field

Tags: ms-access

This is my first database I am building, and am no Access expert, but I do think that I understand the basics.

I have deleted an old field from the back end of a split database, and edited the record sources of the forms that use the table as the record source.  I deleted several fields, but one (a number field) is giving me trouble.  Whether I open the underlying table or the forms that use the table as a recordsource, an "Enter Paramater Value" Dialogue box appears asking for the value on the form.  I have looked at an older version of the database, and the field is not a primary key.  I am quite stumped on this one.  I have confirmed that the field is deleted from the recordsources and the table, so I'm not sure why it is still behaving like this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `Order by` and `Filter` properties of the forms and queries which show such error.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! I had no idea, but they were in the order field on both the form and the table. Thanks!